# How to automatically close a Calendar Icon when mouse click or focus out from specific content?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, calendar, jquery-ui-datepicker, web-frontend

I have calendar attached to the date of birth field when I click on the calendar icon it opens as I need to add the DOB ( Date of Birth ) but for closing the dialogue box I need to click on the close Icon which closes it.

I need to auto close it when I click on any part of the screen or mob to another TAB the it becomes sticky and also showing to the other tab which is vague behavior,

This view build in razor syntax .cshtml pages in C# Dotnet if you ever worked in C# you know what I am talking about.. I also google the solution but didn't make it to achieve what I actually want.

$(#idofmycloseimage).trigger('click')

Where I actually need to define this part of my code in i.e. _Layout.cshtml file which the parent view file for .net framework project in Dotnet.

The line of code working console window during inspect element.

Any related help or solution is highly appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an event listener to the document to close the calendar when clicking outside

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your Page Title</title>
    <!-- Your other head elements -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Your content -->
    @RenderBody()

    <!-- Your other scripts and dependencies -->
    <script>
        // Event listener to close the calendar when clicking outside
        document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            // Check if the click target is not inside the calendar or its trigger element
            var calendarElement = document.getElementById('idOfYourCalendar');
            var triggerElement = document.getElementById('idOfYourCalendarTrigger');

            if (calendarElement && !calendarElement.contains(event.target) && event.target !== triggerElement) {
                // Close the calendar
                // You can trigger a click on the close icon element
                $('#idOfMyCloseImage').trigger('click');
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Make sure to replace 'idOfYourCalendar' with the actual ID of your calendar dialogue box element and 'idOfYourCalendarTrigger' with the ID of the calendar icon or trigger element.

Ensure that 'idOfMyCloseImage' matches the ID of the close icon element in your calendar dialogue box. You can use the same line of code $('#idOfMyCloseImage').trigger('click'); that worked in the console window to trigger the click event of the close icon and close the calendar dialogue box.

By adding this script to your _Layout.cshtml file, the calendar dialogue box will automatically close when you click anywhere outside of it or when you switch to another tab.